# Spring Boot Static content issue

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Edit: I am using Intellij ultimate.

I attempted to look through similar questions but wasn't able to find an answer to help me.

I've gotten CSS to work with spring boot. However, Js still won't function.

I used this statement to get CSS to work.

application.properties

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/
```

and ive added webjar jquery to dependencies

forgive my code its a bit sloppy this is just test file

Html

```
<head>
    <link th:href = "@{../static/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='/webjars/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js'></script>
    <link type="javascript" href="/static/js/script.js">

    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Time Of Day</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I've used both HTML and thyme.

Comment: Remove `spring.web.resources.static-locations` from the properties. Your URL is wrong. Use `@{/css/main.css}` and make sure it is in `src/main/resources/static/css/main.css`.

Comment: I removed the spring.web.resources.static-locations from properties and now the css no longer works. It was working with the code I posted. However, the .js wouldn't work. any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Have you read my comment? Or only applied the firs part of it? There is more to it. And for the js you should do something similar (not for the webjars, but your regular js). Basically the locations should be from the root `/css/main.css` and `/js/script.js` assuming they are in the `src/main/resources/static` directory.

Comment: I did, I used  <script src='/static/js/script.js'></script> to get the js to work. Thanks for the help.